# Not able to upload the artifact using jfrog-cli command line

Tags: artifactory, artifacts, jfrog-cli

I am trying to upload a artifact using following command:

```
jfrog rt u "win_b64" http://localhost:8082/artifactory/Test
```

I am getting the below output:

```
{
"status": "success",
"totals": {
"success": 0,
"failure": 0
}
}
```

But I am not able to see anything on the artifactory.

Comment: Try `jfrog rt u "win_b64" http://localhost:8082/artifactory/Test/`?

Comment: no still getting the same output, but nothing is uploaded

Answer (score 0):

Please try: `jfrog rt u win_b64 Test/`

Can you also specify your OS?

Comment: I am using windows

Answer (score 0):

try `jfrog rt u win_b64 Test/ --url http://localhost:8081/artifactory/ --user admin --password password`

Comment: This can only be used for a file or we can I use it for a folder structure.

Comment: You will have to use regex for folders

Comment: @JainishShah I'm running into this and its impossible to troubleshoot. Why does it say success if it did not upload it?